# word is getting closed for some system

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I am using word interop api in outlook addins for reading word file.

This is working fine for office 2010 with windows 8 and windows 10. but for some of windows 7 (x64) system with office (x86) i am facing problem that word is getting invisible after sometime. I guess this is happening because when i am seeing task manager it opens only one instance and i am doing following operation on word

```
          Private Shared ObjwordApp As Word.Application
          ObjwordApp = New Word.Application()
          ObjwordApp.Visible = False
```

Thank You

Ravi

Edit :- It seems that **word creates single instance** on machines, where the said problem occurs. Meaning if we open word from Outlook Add in by using our interop code and by using user manual intervention. **Both creates single instance of winword.exe.**

I hope it clarifies the issue.

Comment: Your problem is still somewhat unclear. You say "word is getting invisible after sometime". But your code uses: Objwordapp.Visible = false which means your code is setting the application to NOT be visible. So I don't understand your problem - please be more clear.

Comment: I am doing `Objwordapp.Visible = false` for word opening through addins but in some system this is making all word file invisible. if user is working on any word file that also getting invisible

Comment: Yes, Word is "pseudo SDI". But you should only be seeing the behavior if your instance of Word has been created first, before the user tries opening a document. This is a known issue and the work-around is for your code to check whether there's an existing instance of the Word.Application running. If not, create *two*. The first should be the one registered in the ROT that will be handed over to the user and any other processes that use GetActiveObject. The second is the one for your code to use. I'm on a mobile device at the moment, so can't look up the URL of the KB article for you...

Comment: thank you @CindyMeister somehow it is working in some of the systems. So, not sure if we need to change the code or we need to check if there is hot fix available. checked MS site, but could not get any specific KB

Comment: If it's working on some systems, then those have been configured with a different default behavior when the user does whatever is being done to start up the Word application (double-click on a document, for example). This is not a bug and not something you can get a hotfix for. See this KB article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/188546 (and I realize it says "Bug" in the title, but Word is behaving as it was designed to) for the background information.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, Office applications such as Word and Excel register only one instance in the Windows ROT. The default behavior has been that any subsequent action that would start the Office application will be "re-routed" to the instance registered in the ROT. (Reference KB articles https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316125 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238975)

This behavior also applies when code uses GetActiveObject - it picks up the instance registered in the ROT, regardless how many instances of Word may be running. In order to work around that, if you want to be sure your code does *not* share an instance it does not start, the `New` keyword is used to start a new instance of the Word.Application object.

The tricky part is when no existing instance of Word is registered in the ROT. In this case, when you start a new instance it will be the one registered in the ROT and user actions will tend to pick it up, which can cause conflicts. (Reference KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188546/)

The only way to workaround this is to first test whether a running instance (Process) of the Word.Application is available. If there is, using New Word.Application will start a Word instance that is not available to the user.

If there is no Word instance available, your code needs to first start a Word process that it will *not* use, leaving it running for the user. Your code then starts a *second* instance for its own use. It will not be registered in the ROT, so when the user starts Word or double-clicks a document the first instance will be picked up, not the one your application is using.

Note that in recent versions of Windows + Office some (undocumented) changes have taken place that change whether/how Word picks up an instance from the ROT vs. starting a new instance. This is probably why you see varying behavior. But you need to build the workaround into your code in order to be sure there are no conflicts.

Here's a code snippet illustrating the principle of the workaround

```
Process[] wdPcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("WinWord");
int nrWordInstances = wdPcs.Length - 1;
if (nrWordInstances >= 0)
{
  //To pick up other running instance, if you want
  //wdApp = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
  wdApp = new Word.Application();
}
else
{
  //The process that will be registered in the ROT
  //Allows use of command line switches to control how Word starts
  //https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-Word-2007-8be53d5f-9f13-4987-a91e-b272aac5d39d 
  //Note: new Word.Application() is also fine
  ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("winword.exe", "/w");
  Process wdProc = Process.Start(psi);

  //Instance to be used in the running code
  wdApp = new Word.Application();
}
```