# Word Process not closing if other Word document is open

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word

I have a program that receives a Part number from a PLC.  I then use that Part Number to launch an AutoCad drawing, and Word document related to that Part Number.  When another Part Number is received, I want it to close the previous AutoCAD, and Word documents, and reopen them for the new part number.

```vb
Public Sub WordLaunch()

        'Check to see if the Process is already Running. If so, Close it. 
        If myWordProcess.HasExited = False Then
            myWordProcess.CloseMainWindow()
            myWordProcess = Nothing
            MyWordProcessIsRunning = False
        End If

        For Each line As String In lines
            WordParts = line.Trim.Split("|"c)
            If WordParts.Length = 2 Then
                WordPreLetter = WordParts(1) ' Read PreLetter Ex A-, B-, Etc
                'Open Fix Ref. with Word
                If File.Exists(txtFixRefDirectory.Text & "\" & WordPreLetter & TrimmedIncomming & "." & txtFixRefExt.Text) Then
                    'OpenFile
                    WordProcessProperties.FileName = txtWordPath.Text
                    WordProcessProperties.Arguments = """" & txtFixRefDirectory.Text & "\" & WordPreLetter & TrimmedIncomming & "." & txtFixRefExt.Text & """"
                    WordProcessProperties.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
                    myWordProcess = Process.Start(WordProcessProperties)
                    MyWordProcessIsRunning = True
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

The issue I'm having, is if another Word document has been opened by the user, my program will stop closing the Word Document. Before you know it,  there are 20 open word docs running on the PC. AutoCAD is working as expected. If the user opens an AutoCAD drawing on their own, and then my program opens one, when the next part number is received, only the drawing that had previously been opened from my program will close. Any idea why Word is behaving differently?

Comment: Impossible to answer as you do not provide a [mcve]. The code you show does not use the standard Word libraries, so there's no way of knowing what it's actually doing, we can only guess at what's actually happening. On the whole, however, you wouldn't have the problem if the Word document being opened would instantiate a Word.Document object by using the Word COM `Documents.Open` command. Or, at the very least, loop a `Word.Application` object's `Documents` collection and assign the document to a `Document` object. Then it's possible to run the `Close` method on that object.

Comment: Beyond that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555178/word-is-getting-closed-for-some-system/35582076#35582076 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324083/prevent-user-from-attaching-to-run-by-developer-instance-of-ms-office-process/54326239#54326239 for information about sharing instances of Word with the user (or not).